# Oracle : Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, eof

I'm facing a strange problem. It's shows me:

> ERROR at line 28: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

the code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION st_atten_up(stu_id IN student_info.id%type,app_mon IN student_attendence.month%type)
RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
        att1 NUMBER; 
        CURSOR c1(sid IN student_info.id%type, pmon IN student_attendence.month%type) IS
        SELECT ATTENDANCE
        FROM STUDENT_ATTENDENCE
        WHERE id = sid and month = pmon;

    -- You may want a smaller variable if you know the result will be smaller
    BEGIN
        open c1;
        fetch c1(stu_id,app_mon) into att1;
        c1;

        att1 :=att1 + 1;
        UPDATE STUDENT_ATTENDENCE
        SET STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.ATTENDANCE = att1
        where STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.ID = stu_id and STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.month = app_mon;
        COMMIT;
        return att1;

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    END;
```

I  don't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Is that `/` at the end in the actual file, or just your code block? Cause it looks like that is the problem.

Comment: no just in the code block @Gray

Comment: Ah, ok, and is that the entire error message? It seems like it is about to list something. "expecting one of the following..."?

Comment: no it's like      
    ERROR at line 28: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map

1.     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION st_atten_up(stu_id IN student_info.id%type,app_mon IN student_attendence.month%type)
2.       RETURN NUMBER
3.     IS
4.       PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

Comment: Change your update statement to single line instead of 3 lines and close your cursor (Replace c1; line with close c1;). See if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you remove the C1 form the middle of code and check I have done the same in below code please check and let me know.

```
BEGIN
    open c1;
    fetch c1(stu_id,app_mon) into att1;
    --c1; remove it and try

    att1 :=att1 + 1;
    UPDATE STUDENT_ATTENDENCE
    SET STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.ATTENDANCE = att1
    where STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.ID = stu_id and STUDENT_ATTENDENCE.month = app_mon;
    COMMIT;
    return att1;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we've reached consensus that the problem is the line which reads `c1;` - which should probably be `close c1;`.  I'm going to suggest a slightly different solution - that being, use a cursor FOR loop instead of a standalone cursor, and exit the loop after a single iteration.  This completely eliminates the need to check for no data being fetched (which isn't done in the original) and IMO makes the code easier to read and comprehend:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION st_atten_up(stu_id IN student_info.id%type,
                                       app_mon IN student_attendence.month%type)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT ID, MONTH, ATTENDANCE
                 FROM STUDENT_ATTENDENCE
                 WHERE ID = stu_id AND
                       MONTH = app_mon)
  LOOP
    aRow.ATTENDANCE := aRow.ATTENDANCE + 1;

    UPDATE STUDENT_ATTENDENCE
      SET ATTENDANCE = aRow.ATTENDANCE
      WHERE ID = aRow.ID and
            MONTH = aRow.MONTH;
    COMMIT;

    RETURN aRow.STUDENT_ATTENDANCE;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN NULL;  -- no data found in FOR loop
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || '  ' || SQLERRM);
    ROLLBACK;
    raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END ST_ATTEN_UP;
```

Share and enjoy.